# Link breaking due to padding only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have been a front-end developer for quite some time and have not encountered this problem until today.  In my main nav, I am using a large amount of right padding so that my hover dropdowns have a wide range.

Basically, my problem lies within this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="main-wrap">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/"><img src="" alt="" /></a>
        </div><!--end logo-->
        <div class="mobile-logo">
            <a href="/"><img src="" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="main-nav" aria-hidden="false" role="menubar">
            <li><a href="">Future Students</a><img class="nav-arrow" alt="" src="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="">Future Students</a><img class="nav-arrow" alt="" src="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="">Future Students</a><img class="nav-arrow" alt="" src="" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="">Future Students</a><img class="nav-arrow" alt="" src="" /></a></li>
        </ul><!--end main-nav-->
    </div><!--end main-wrap-->
</div><!--end header-->
```

**CSS:**

```
#header .main-wrap .main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 146px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 7px 15px 0px 22px;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid #782f40;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#header .main-wrap .main-nav li a {
    font-family: 'open-sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 33px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

I know this is very basic, but for some reason I cannot figure out what is causing this problem.  In Chrome and IE, everything looks/works great.  However in Firefox, the links are breaking to three lines and the text in the anchor will not fill the width of the list item. Anyone know a quick solution?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ak5teLof/

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of reasons that may be causing the issue.

1. **Text not filling space:** You have a set width of 146px on the `li` tag in the menu. By default text will only stay inside its containers. The total length of the text is longer than 146px, so by setting the width of the menu at a hard width, the text then wraps onto the next line to fit into the set width.

**Solutiuon: Set the width on your `li` to `auto`**

2. **Link wrapping onto 3 lines:** This is because you have a large `padding-bottom` value of 33px on your `a` tag. Padding on an element by default will *increase* the size of the element, especially top and bottom padding. So your total link height composes of: 2 x lines of text + 33px.

**Solution: Change the `padding-bottom` value on your `a` tag to be either nothing, or just reduce it down to a value you're happy with e.g. 5px or 0.2em - depending on what you're trying to achieve.**

Comment: Samuel, Thanks for your response. However, neither solution solves my problem.  I have the li width and the padding-bottom set for specific reasons.  Also, changing either of these does not solve my problem.  In Chrome and IE, the links fill the 146 px of the li, but for some reason in Firefox, the text will not fill the full width of the list item.  I have the padding bottom set so that the hover can be extended, changing it to 0 does not solve this issue.  Any ideas?